# Twitter OAuth Implementation in Google App Engine Using google oauth java client library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I have created a Web application in Google App Engine java. Now I want to provide the authentication functionality. User can use his twitter(in future I will provide other OAuth Service provider too) account for login. I have found couple of libraries for twitter authentication like twitter4j. I don't want to use any such kind of library that specifically work for single social site like Twitter, facebook etc. I thought to do oauth implementation by my self. I have pretty good knowledge about oauth mechanism and found google oauth java client library. This library provide the functionality of oauth and is not dependent to any kind of social site(to my knowledge). Unfortunately I didn't find good examples on this library. Can any one help me about the examples, tutorials or any other library that is not dependent to any particular social site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer http://planet.jboss.org/post/setting_up_google_oauth2_with_java as well as http://googlecode.blogspot.in/2011/09/google-apis-client-library-for-java-now.html links

Comment: I have checked the given link. The example they provide are specifically for Google authentication. I am searching for a generic example.